# Cannot unregister type library xxx - cannot load file, check to make sure it's a valid type library

Tags: visual-studio

After editing a previously-working solution, visual studio 2010 will no longer compile the project and is giving me the following error:

> Cannot unregister type library {library name} - cannot load file, check to make sure it's a valid type library.

I did quite a bit of searching on the web but there was precious little to be found on this error. What can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no idea what caused the error, but it turns out the solution was very easy--just close all instances of Visual Studio and then re-open your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes these errors can be fixed just by cleaning the solution:

Build -> Clean Solution, then Build -> Build Solution

Comment: The "Or" confuses me. Please describe and explain the solution you propose.

Comment: @Don J. Slogar, thank you for your contribution. The StackOverflow community aims to build clearly explained answers for all levels of its members. Whilst answering questions, please remember our aim to build a better knowledge base.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).